# Smooth Scroll works only from the same page and not from external links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to a wordpress paid theme (Gavick - Creativity) and it uses the code below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // SmoothScroll jQUery substitue
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
            $target = jQuery(target);

        if ($target.length) {
            jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 150
                //'scrollTop': $target.offset().top   ORIGINAL
            }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
               window.location.hash = target+150;
                //window.location.hash = target;  ORIGINAL
            });
        } else {
           window.location.hash = target;
            // window.location.hash = target;   ORIGINAL
        }

    });
```

The thing is that it smooth scrolls only from internal links and not from external.

When I am at the same page and click on an anchor link it scrolls perfectly.
Visiting the page anchor from another page doesn't scroll at all.

All I need is to visit http://domain.com/#anchortag and scroll to it from the start of the page.
I also need to be able to have different offsets if I am in the same page or in an external one.

Any help?

Comment: The external link don't implement your javascript code .... That's why you don't have the smooth scrolling. Or maybe i'm just missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first thing

> Visiting the page anchor from another page doesn't scroll at all.

You can make a jQuery function to check for that case:

```
function checkForAnchor() {
  var pathname = jQuery(location).attr('href');
  pathname = pathname.split("#");

  for(var i = 0; i < pathname.length; i++){
    if(pathname[i] == 'YOUR ANCHOR'){
      jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: (jQuery('.YOUR CONTAINER TO SCROLL TO').offset().top)}, 'slow');
    }
  }
}
```

> I also need to be able to have different offsets if I am in the same page or in an external one.

Therefore you may use a cookie. When the user visits your page first and there is no cookie you can use another offset to scroll to. After that set a cookie and use a different offset.